# IndexOutofbouds at game's world rendering

Tags: java, 2d, rendering

I posted this on the Gamedev stackexchange, and was suggested to post it here instead. I have an array, that essentially contains 16*16 blocks. When I press the wasd keys, the world moves, all the tiles get smashed up into eachother, like the grass tiles here do:
[image: http://puu.sh/6g0hp.png]

and shortly into the move I get an IndexOutOfBounds exception. either 400 or -1. What should I be doing instead of moving renderX and renderY, to get this to work?
My latest try:

```
package net.makerimages.sandbox.world;

import net.makerimages.sandbox.block.*;
import net.makerimages.sandbox.world.biome.Biomes;
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Input;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame;

import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Created by Makerimages on 5.01.14.
 */
public class World
{
    private Biomes currentGeneratorBiome;
    private Random rand=new Random();
    private int worldSeed;
    public  Block[][] worldContents=new Block[400][400];
    public  BlockDirt blockDirt=new BlockDirt(0,this);
    public  BlockAir blockAir=new BlockAir(1,this);
    public  BlockStone blockStone=new BlockStone(2,this);
    public  BlockGrass blockGrass=new BlockGrass(3,this);
    public  BlockCobbleStone blockCobbleStone=new BlockCobbleStone(4,this);
    public  BlockSand blockSand=new BlockSand(5,this);
    public  int renderX=-1;
    public  int renderY=-1;
    public  World() throws SlickException {
    }

    public void renderWorld(GameContainer gameContainer)
    {
        int xmin= renderX/16;
        int xmax=  renderX+800/16;
        int ymin= renderY/16;
        int ymax=renderY+600/16;
        for(int x=xmin;x< xmax;x++)
        {
            for(int y=ymin;y<ymax;y++)
            {

                if (x < 0) x = 0;
                if (y < 0) y = 0;
                if (x >= 400) x = 400; // width of map
                if (y >= 400) y = 400; // height of map
                worldContents[x][y].draw(x*16-renderX,y*16-renderY);


            }
        }      Input I=gameContainer.getInput();
        if(I.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_S))
        {
            renderY++;
        }
        if(I.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_W))
        {
            renderY--;
        }
        if(I.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_A))
        {
            renderX--;
        }
        if(I.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_D))
        {
            renderX++;
        }

    }

    public void generateNewWorld()
    {
        int startY=7;
        int placementY;
        int currentY=startY;
        Random rand=new Random();

        for(int x=0; x<worldContents.length;x++)
        {

            //Plainlands biome
            int upDown=rand.nextInt(45);
            if(upDown>22)
            {
                placementY=currentY+rand.nextInt(2);
            }
            else
            {
                placementY=currentY-rand.nextInt(2);
                if(placementY<0)
                {
                    placementY=-placementY;
                }
            }

            worldContents[x][placementY]=blockDirt;
            for(int y=placementY+1;y<worldContents[0].length-(placementY+1);y++)
            {
                worldContents[x][y]=blockStone;
            }

            currentY=placementY;

        }
        for(int xP=0;xP<worldContents.length;xP++)
        {
            for(int yP=0;yP<worldContents[0].length;yP++)
                if(worldContents[xP][yP]==null)
                {
                    worldContents[xP][yP]=blockAir;
                }
        }
    }
    public  Block getBlockAt(int x, int y)
    {
        return worldContents[x][y];
    }

    public void setBlockAt(int x, int y, Block block)
    {
        worldContents[x][y]=block;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define your world here:

```
public  Block[][] worldContents=new Block[400][400];
```

as a 400x400 2D array. Definition of an array requires that you note the exact size of the array you would like, in this case (400 and 400), but when accessing the array indexes start from 0 meaning you can only count to 399 before you get an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

so  change

```
if (x >= 400) x = 400;
if (y >= 400) y = 400;
```

to

```
if (x >= 399) x = 399;
if (y >= 399) y = 399;
```

or

```
if (x >= worldContents[0].length) x = worldContents[0].length;
if (y >= worldContents.length) y = worldContents.length;
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You might be accessing the index 400 of the array. Here

```
if (x >= 400) x = 400; // width of map
if (y >= 400) y = 400; // height of map``
worldContents[x][y].draw(x*16-renderX,y*16-renderY);
```

Your `worldContents` is a 400x400 matrix, which means the indexes go from 0 to 399.